Sharing a document for a limited time period whilst preventing copy and paste
I want a web app that allows me to share a document to another person, and they can only access it from/to the time/date I define, so it in essence expires.
Whilst it's shared, I want to prevent things like download, copy, paste, etc.
I know there are various ways that a person can photograph or screenshot it, but I'd like to prevent the easiest ways of it being copied.
Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Simply stream it with anything like OBS Studio. No cutting/copying, no downloading if it's streamed to a platform that doesn't make that easy, e.g. Twitch with archiving disabled.
Although I have no idea who this is catered towards, who doesn't know how to take a screenshot and then Google how to read text from it, yet is a danger in terms of copying/stealing.
